# Android Bluetooth LE - sending response on characteristic indication

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have successfully subscribed to indications on a Bluetooth GATT characteristic for a blood pressure monitor in an Android app, and measurement data is correctly being delivered via the onCharacteristicChanged callback.  I have read from multiple sources that the difference between Notifications and Indications in Bluetooth LE is that Indications require a response to be sent from the GATT client to the server once the data has been delivered, while Notifications do not.

Does anyone know exactly what response should be sent from the Android client to the GATT server upon Indication?  Is there a typical or generic response that you send, or does it vary by device?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide source for reading blood characteristic, please? i am trying to read pulse rate/ Thanks anyway. sergeysheleg4@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response that is sent back is listed as a "Handle Value Confirmation" by my particular BLE sniffer. This is automatically sent by the BLE hardware on the phone, and is not handled by the Android App. This is mainly a consideration of the BLE device, and not the Android phone.

Comment: @Ben Ward is it correct? we dont have to send any ack mannually? In MI band I am only getting 1 stream of data as indication. do I need to send any acknowledge?